# Using results in one query to use in another query - Orace MySql

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to use the results of the first query and place into the second query, sorry if this doesn't make much sense, im new to all of this.

First Query

```html
SELECT "NAME", "TYPE","CATEGORY" "Meters" FROM BBT_Locations
WHERE SQRT(Power((:myLocX-LOCX), 2) + Power((:MyLocY - LOCY),2)) < :Distance;
```

Second Query

```html
Select Round((:Distance/20)*4)as "Meters";
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier just to use Round((:Distance/20)*4) in the first query?

Comment: yes it would, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please elaborate more as in which field value of 1st query you would like to use in 2nd query ? There are **JOIN query** and **Sub query** concept in SQL which can be used. But we should know the field that we would like to use and get value for, based on that we can select the kind of query to write.